# Cot caught merger - /ɔɪ/ or /ɑɪ/ in boy, choice...?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, phonology, linguistics, phonetics

Here is the [pronunciation guide from Oxford American English dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/about/pronunciation_american_english):

> Some speakers only use the sound /ɔ/ when it is followed by /r/ (as in horse /hɔrs/) and use /ɑ/ in all other words that are shown with /ɔ/ in this dictionary, so that they pronounce both caught and cot as /kɑt/.

It means that ɔɪ will become ɑɪ . Boy will be pronounced /bɑɪ/, choice will be pronounced /tʃɑɪs/.

Could anyone confirm this is the actual pronunciation of the people with cot/caught merger? Or do they just keep /bɔɪ/ and /tʃɔɪs/?

If /bɑɪ/ is used, will it be easy to distinguish with buy /baɪ/ ?

PS: I am interested in American English by Oxford dictionary. But I get confused with their guide as mentioned in my question. Will boy be pronounced /bɑɪ/ according to their guide ? If a particular region must be specified, please take a US region with cot caught merger to see how they pronounce boy, choice... I want to make sure that /bɑɪ/ pronunciation is practical and recognized by most of listeners

Comment: "the people with cot/caught merger" [aren't a homogenous group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cot%E2%80%93caught_merger): it's found in Scotland and other parts of the British Isles, parts of the US and Canada, and elsewhere. Are you interested in a particular dialect/region? You could start with [the chart here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects).

Comment: I am interested in American English by Oxford dictionary. But I get confused with their guide as mentioned in my question. Will boy be pronounced /bɑɪ/ according to their guide ? If a particular region must be specified, let's take a US region with cot caught merger to see how they pronounce boy, choice... I want to make sure that /bɑɪ/ pronunciation is practical and recognized by most of listeners

Answer (score 3):

*Oxford Dictionary* is only talking about the phoneme /ɔ/, and not the phoneme /ɔɪ/. These are two different phonemes, and they probably didn't realize they were being ambiguous when they wrote their pronunciation guide. To American English ears, /bɑɪ/ sounds like *buy* and not /bɔɪ/. If you pronounce *boy* as /bɑɪ/, you will probably be misunderstood.

I can't say for sure that there isn't some region of the United States where they pronounce *boy* as /bɑɪ/, but certainly in nearly all the accents with the COT-CAUGHT merger that I've run into, *boy* pronounced something like /bɔɪ/.

The [Wikipedia International Phonetic Alphabet Chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects) gives /ɔɪ/ or /oɪ/ for the pronunciation of the phoneme /ɔɪ/ in nearly all the American dialects they list, and don't list any dialects where it's pronounced /ɑɪ/. So if you want to avoid the phone [ɔ] altogether, you could pronounce *horse* as /hors/ and *boy* as /boɪ/.

Comment: It's confusing, they say "Some speakers only use the sound /ɔ/ when it is followed by /r/ (as in horse /hɔrs/)". It means that they understand ɔr as 2 different phonemes, not a phoneme. So, the same for ɔɪ - they are 2 different phonemes, not a phoneme. Anyways, thanks for your clarification, boy should be pronounced /bɔɪ/, not /bɑɪ/

Comment: @NamN Probably *boy*, *bore*, and *boat* have the same syllabic nucleus: /o/.

Comment: @Nam N: In the standard analysis of American English, /ɔɪ/ is considered a single phoneme, which is a diphthong (so there are two symbols), while /ɔr/ is often considered as two phonemes. (Not that you could tell this from their *guide to pronunciation*.)